# Adding Event listener to CKEDITOR plugin

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm creating CKEDITOR plugin. Suppose, I have following:

```js
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('internallink', {
    icons: 'internallink',
    toolbar: 'insert,100',

    init: function (editor) {
      
        editor.addCommand('internallink', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('internalLinkDialog'));

        editor.ui.addButton('InternalLink', {
            label: 'Internal link',
            command: 'internallink',
            toolbar: 'links'
        });

        CKEDITOR.dialog.add('internalLinkDialog', function (editor) {

            return {
                title: 'Internal link',
                minWidth: 600,
                minHeight: 400,
                contents: [
                    {
                        id: 'tab-main',
                        label: 'Select page',
                        elements: [
                            {
                                type: 'select',
                                id: 'page_tree',
                                label: 'Select page',
                                items: [[1],[2],[3]],
                            },
                        ]
                    }
                ],
            };
        });
    }
});
```

I want a tooltip to appear while hovering one of select options.
How can I insert event listener for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

option element doesn't have onMouseOver event.
That's it )

Comment: Would you be able to give some explanations about how you answered this question?